# SQL Count of columns result for all existing Dates in the table

Tags: sql

I have a table DTTransaction and DTHotelTransaction with TransactionID is the primary key in former and foreign key in later.

```
Columns in DTTransaction  :machinename(varchar),BookedOn(datetime),TransactionID(int) 
Columns in DTHotelTransaction :HCOMCID(int) ,TransactionID
```

Requirement :

For every BookedOn value in DTTransaction  , I want the machine name and count of machinename for these (415428,415429,415430,415431,415432) HCOMCID.

I am trying to do :

```
select DTTransaction.machinename,count(DTTransaction.machinename) from DTTransaction   
join DTHotelReservation on DTTransaction.TransactionID =      
DTHotelReservation.TransactionID
and DTHotelReservation.HCOMCID in (
415428,
415429,
415430,
415431,
415432)
where convert(varchar(10),BookedOn,101)='04/10/2013'
group by DTTransaction.machinename
```

But it will give only for a particular date.I want to get the count for all existing BookedOn values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the sum of all dates, just remove the `where` clause:

```
select DTTransaction.machinename, count(DTTransaction.machinename)
from DTTransaction join
     DTHotelReservation
     on DTTransaction.TransactionID = DTHotelReservation.TransactionID and
        DTHotelReservation.HCOMCID in (415428, 415429, 415430, 415431, 415432)
group by DTTransaction.machinename
```

If you want the results by date, then include that in your `group by`.  For instance,

```
select DTTransaction.machinename, convert(varchar(10),BookedOn,101), count(DTTransaction.machinename)
from DTTransaction join
     DTHotelReservation
     on DTTransaction.TransactionID = DTHotelReservation.TransactionID and
        DTHotelReservation.HCOMCID in (415428, 415429, 415430, 415431, 415432)
group by DTTransaction.machinename, convert(varchar(10),BookedOn,101)
order by 1, MAX(BookedOn)
```

I included an `order by` clause, so the results will be in order by date within each machine name.